# Is there a way to retrieve file names and links from dropbox public folder without authorization?

Tags: php, dropbox

For example, if I don't have dropbox account and have public link to some folder. So I can go to this link using web browser, find with my eyes file I need and download it.

I need to do the same with php script (find and download file from public folder).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there isn't a way to use their APIs without authenticating first.
On public folders specifically, Dropbox is actually deprecating their use (see https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/19/new-sharing-model-will-replace-public-folder - new accounts don't have them anymore).

Comment: Sorry, I thought public=shared. In my question I mean shared folder.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague explained me: service don't want to allow scripts make a large amount of traffic.